# Do you risk giving 3party plugins access to your source code when installing them in intellij

Tags: jpa, intellij-plugin, intellij-2020

opened my git repo in itellij 2021.2.1 it is a java project built with mvn and a sql db.
So a few recommendations for plugins pops up and my question is what do they mean by this warning sign for JPA Buddy 5.4-212 plugin?

"Using third party plugin may involve a plugin vendor processing your personal data. Please check the plugin vendor'r documentation fro details concerning personal data processing.

JetBrains is not responsible for any processing of your personal data by any third-party plugin vendors".

Tried to look into the documentation but didn't find the answer to my question if this plugin is unsafe, in that I expose my data or data model to this 3 party plugin vendor. What type of data is personal data in this case?

https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/15075-jpa-buddy/features

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I represent the plugin development team and can confirm that we don't gather any client info. The only way to share something is to send an exception report, but this doesn't go out automatically; a developer should press the button to send it over.

However, it is a good question. You could probably track outgoing traffic from your workstation to make sure nothing sensitive leaves it.